# Fetching individual figure with sum case, monthly data issue

Tags: mysql, database

I am calculating GST to be paid yearly monthly by GST percentage wise on total sale.  It is giving me correct data, but when applying condition it gives me yearly data instead of monthly data.

In the below code, I was doing it without `"AND p.gst_tax = 5 || p.gst_tax = 12 || p.gst_tax = 18"`

But I figured that it is giving me wrong data of total yearly GST amount because at product level some only products are not mapped with GST slab, so I added the above line in YTD total GST to get only those which have 5-12-18 in the field yearly, and it worked fine.

I was getting `gst_mt_dtotal` correct, but to make sure that if in future any product added in orders table which is not mapped to GST slab should not be counted, I added the same code in `gst_mtd` (monthly) too .. and to the surprise it gave the same figure it was giving me in yearly which is wrong, I cant figure out why this happened? anyone can help please ??

Am I using the correct way to calculating GST amount tax slab wise ?? Please guide.

```
SELECT 
--yearly
SUM(CASE 
    WHEN o.created_on >= CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-04-01')
    AND o.created_on  < CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-04-01') + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
    AND p.gst_tax = 5 || p.gst_tax = 12 || p.gst_tax = 18
    THEN op.gst_tax_value ELSE 0 end) as pos_gst_total_ytd,


SUM(CASE 
    WHEN o.created_on >= CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-04-01')
    AND o.created_on  < CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-04-01') + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
    AND p.gst_tax = 5
    THEN op.gst_tax_value ELSE 0 end) as pos_gst_5_ytd,
SUM(CASE 
    WHEN o.created_on >= CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-04-01')
    AND o.created_on  < CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-04-01') + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
    AND p.gst_tax = 12
    THEN op.gst_tax_value ELSE 0 end) as pos_gst_12_ytd,
SUM(CASE 
    WHEN o.created_on >= CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-04-01')
    AND o.created_on  < CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-04-01') + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
    AND p.gst_tax = 18
    THEN op.gst_tax_value ELSE 0 end) as pos_gst_18_ytd,
   --monthly 
SUM(CASE
    WHEN YEAR(o.created_on) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
    AND MONTH(o.created_on) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
    AND p.gst_tax = 5 || p.gst_tax = 12 || p.gst_tax = 18
    THEN op.gst_tax_value ELSE 0 end) as pos_gst_total_mtd,
SUM(CASE
    WHEN YEAR(o.created_on) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
    AND MONTH(o.created_on) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
    AND p.gst_tax = 5
    THEN op.gst_tax_value ELSE 0 end) as pos_gst_5_mtd,
SUM(CASE
    WHEN YEAR(o.created_on) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
    AND MONTH(o.created_on) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
    AND p.gst_tax = 12
    THEN op.gst_tax_value ELSE 0 end) as pos_gst_12_mtd,
SUM(CASE
    WHEN YEAR(o.created_on) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
    AND MONTH(o.created_on) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
    AND p.gst_tax = 18
    THEN op.gst_tax_value ELSE 0 end) as pos_gst_18_mtd    
FROM
   pos_order_products op
   LEFT JOIN pos_orders o ON o.order_id = op.pos_order_id
   LEFT JOIN product p ON p.id = op.product_id
   AND op.is_deleted = 0
   AND o.is_deleted = 'N'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put your OR condition in braces like this - (`p.gst_tax = 5 || p.gst_tax = 12 || p.gst_tax = 18)`

```
SELECT 
--yearly
SUM(CASE 
    WHEN o.created_on >= CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-04-01')
    AND o.created_on  < CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-04-01') + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
    AND (p.gst_tax = 5 || p.gst_tax = 12 || p.gst_tax = 18)
    THEN op.gst_tax_value ELSE 0 end) as pos_gst_total_ytd,


SUM(CASE 
    WHEN o.created_on >= CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-04-01')
    AND o.created_on  < CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-04-01') + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
    AND p.gst_tax = 5
    THEN op.gst_tax_value ELSE 0 end) as pos_gst_5_ytd,
SUM(CASE 
    WHEN o.created_on >= CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-04-01')
    AND o.created_on  < CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-04-01') + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
    AND p.gst_tax = 12
    THEN op.gst_tax_value ELSE 0 end) as pos_gst_12_ytd,
SUM(CASE 
    WHEN o.created_on >= CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-04-01')
    AND o.created_on  < CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()), '-04-01') + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
    AND p.gst_tax = 18
    THEN op.gst_tax_value ELSE 0 end) as pos_gst_18_ytd,
   --monthly 
SUM(CASE
    WHEN YEAR(o.created_on) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
    AND MONTH(o.created_on) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
    AND (p.gst_tax = 5 || p.gst_tax = 12 || p.gst_tax = 18)
    THEN op.gst_tax_value ELSE 0 end) as pos_gst_total_mtd,
SUM(CASE
    WHEN YEAR(o.created_on) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
    AND MONTH(o.created_on) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
    AND p.gst_tax = 5
    THEN op.gst_tax_value ELSE 0 end) as pos_gst_5_mtd,
SUM(CASE
    WHEN YEAR(o.created_on) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
    AND MONTH(o.created_on) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
    AND p.gst_tax = 12
    THEN op.gst_tax_value ELSE 0 end) as pos_gst_12_mtd,
SUM(CASE
    WHEN YEAR(o.created_on) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
    AND MONTH(o.created_on) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
    AND p.gst_tax = 18
    THEN op.gst_tax_value ELSE 0 end) as pos_gst_18_mtd    
FROM
   pos_order_products op
   LEFT JOIN pos_orders o ON o.order_id = op.pos_order_id
   LEFT JOIN product p ON p.id = op.product_id
   AND op.is_deleted = 0
   AND o.is_deleted = 'N'
```

Comment: yes thanks . .its working now .. but why ? can you please describe it how it executes ?
and is there any other way to do it ? as its really long query with 2 joins , how can i make it simpler ?

Comment: when you've multiple OR condition along with AND then put in the braces or the best option is you can use IN clause like p.gst_tax in (5,12,18) @AnshM

Comment: how to mark as accepted ? i am new here.. upvoted your answer , but it says it wont display as i dont have that much reputation .

Comment: @AnshM, there is a green tick - you've to click that :)